# Atomic bit-wise operations on POD type

Tags: c++, atomic

Given the following:

```
#include<atomic>

struct Foo
{
    uint64_t data[1];
};

std::atomic<Foo> bar;

void DoAtomicOr(uint64_t value)
{
    std::atomic_fetch_or(&bar, value);
}
```

My compiler is complaining that the type of the first parameter cannot be passed into the fetch because its type doesn't match any known overloads.  I can typecast it to:

```
std::atomic_fetch_or((std::atomic<uint64_t> *)&bar, value);
```

But this is error prone as I already proved to myself early today.  Is there a better way to get the compiler to realize that he Pod type `Foo` here is actually just a glorified `uint64_t`?

Comment: The compiler is right: `MyData` is not an atomic type. `MyData.bar` is.

Comment: Dang it - let me adjust question

Comment: Typed it in wrong like a genius.  I may close this and re-open it with the corrections.  I promise this isn't a syntax error issue.

Comment: Why not just `bar.fetch_or(value);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Foo` is not an `integral` type and therefore you cannot use `fetch_or()`.

One solution is to use `data[1]` (instead of `Foo`) as an `atomic` type:

```
struct Foo
{
    std::atomic<uint64_t> data[1];
};

Foo bar;

void DoAtomicOr(uint64_t value)
{
    std::atomic_fetch_or(&bar.data[0], value);
}
```

In case you want to keep `Foo` `atomic`, you can use a compare-and-swap with an OR operation:

```
struct Foo
{
    uint64_t data[1];
};

std::atomic<Foo> bar;

void DoAtomicOr(uint64_t value)
{
    Foo expected = bar.load();
    Foo desired;

    do {
        desired = expected;

        desired.data[0] |= value;

    } while (!std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&bar, &expected, desired));
}
```

Comment: Funny thing is, your second answer is actually what the compiler is asm generating when I do it right.  I was just hoping for a little more "support" from the language.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Glad I could help ;]